# Need a lot of help making a square class

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a square class using Dr. Java. I have taken most of the code from a rectangle class but it has left me with a mess. I'm currently a beginner when it comes to Java so I'm really lost right now. If you have any correction or tips on how to correct my square class please let me know. Thanks

```
    package graphics2;

/**
 * A class that represents a square with given origin, width, and height.
 */
public class Square extends Graphics {
  // The private width and height of this square.
  private double width = 0;
  private double height = 0;  

  /**
   * Constructs a square with given origin, width, and height.
   */
  public Square(Point origin, double side) {
    super(origin, side, side);
    setOrigin(new Point(0, 0));
    width = height = side;
}

  /**
   * Constructs a square with given width and height at origin (0, 0).
   */
  public Square(double side) {
    setOrigin(new Point(0, 0));
    width = height = side;
  }
  /**
   * Returns the square's side of this square.
   */
  public double  getSide() {return width;}

  /**
   * Returns the width coordinate of this square.
   */
  public double getWidth() {return width; }

  /**
   * Returns the height coordinate of this square.
   */
  public double getHeight() {return height; }

  /**
   * Returns the area of this square.
   */
  public double area() {
    return width * height;
  }
}
```

Also here is the error I'm receiving:

```
    1 error found:
File: C:\Users\GreatOne\Desktop\06Labs-\graphics2\Square.java  [line: 15]
Error: The constructor graphics2.Graphics(graphics2.Point, double, double) is undefined
```

Comment: You have not declared the variables, so how do you expect to use them? Also, are you sure you want to derive from `Graphics`? Is your square really a graphics context?

Answer (score 5):

Chris, don't extend Graphics.  That's very wrong.  Don't extend anything.

Your constructors need correction, they're not matching up with how you're trying to create Squares.

Also you are missing multiple variables.

I would suggest rather than have someone on stackoverflow sort out this mess, you open up your textbook or read some tutorials online.  I can fix this in minutes for you, but it won't help you as I'm skeptical you'll understand how to use it.

Please study up.  You'll be better for it.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep studying and trying. I've just been messing with it all day and I'm about to reach a deadline so I posted it here

Comment: I've been there before, I can appreciate that.  I'm not trying to call you out here, just giving you the advice I wish I'd been strong enough to follow 100% the time in college.  Good luck man.

Answer (score 0):

Your code explained according to the errors :

**Errors**

- **Error 1  [line: 15]** :Constructor undefined. What you want is `super(origin, side);`, instead of `super(origin, side, side);` I assume. Either that, or you should define the constructor with `super(origin, side, side);`
- **Error 2,3,4,5 [line: 17, 18, 26, 27]**: You are using variables `w` and `h` inside the constructors, without having them as method parameters. Since this is a square you want, change `width = w` and `height = h` to `width = side` and `height = side` in both the constructors. As you are passing the variable `side` in the method parameter, this will not create a problem.
- **Last error [line: 32]** : You are returning the variable `side` in the getter method `public double  getSide()`. Since `side` is not a variable of the class, it shows an error. Change that to `return width` or `return height`. Since this is a square, both will be equal.

Comment: Thanks @aksh1t I have fixed all the errors except for the 1st one. I know I need to define uper(origin, side, side); but im not sure how to change it.

Comment: Well, about the `super(origin,side,side)` line, you will have to see in the current class's superclass (i.e Graphics) whether there is a constructor in it like `Graphics(Point origin, double side, double side)`. If not, then you will have to make it. Or you could replace your line `super(origin,side,side)` with a constructor which __is__ defined in the `Graphics` class.